# Unable to format JSON response with PHP Arrays

Tags: php, arrays, json, formatting

I want the following JSON:

```
{"success": false,"errors": {"err1": "some error","err2": "another error"}}
```

The code I am using:

```
$rs = array("success"=>true);
$rs['errors'][] = array("err1"=>"some error");
$rs['errors'][] = array("err2"=>"another error");
json_encode($rs);
```

produces the following:

```
{"success":false,"errors":[{"err1":"some error"},{"err2":"another error"}]}
```

Answer (score 4):

`errors` should be an associative array.

```
$rs = array('success' => false, 'errors' => array());
$rs['errors']['err1'] = 'some error';
$rs['errors']['err2'] = 'another error';
echo json_encode($rs);
```

Comment: This is correct, but I wanted to point out that it's not necessary to declare `$rs['errors']` as an associative array (or even as part of `$rs` at all). PHP will automatically add the index to the array if it doesn't exist when `$rs['errors']['err1'] = 'some error';` is executed.

Comment: @Matt: I realize that and prefer to declare all used objects explicitly. It can be removed, yes.

Comment: I was certain you knew this; I just wanted to point it out to anyone else reading your answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

`errors` contains a single object, not multiple objects in a numeric array. This should work:

```
$a = array(
  "success" => false,
  "errors" => array(
    "err1" => "some error",
    "err2" => "another error"
  )
);
json_encode($a);
```

Comment: Thanks all for your responses.   Such a great forum and a great group of professionals.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON string you are trying to create does not have any arrays in it. It has nested objects. You would need to create an object in order to replicate that JSON string like this:

```
$root_obj = new StdClass();
$root_obj->success = false;
$root_obj->errors = new StdClass();
$root_obj->errors->err1 = 'some error';
$root_obj->errors->err2 = 'another error';
```